# How to change tab on onScrollChanged in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on the screen where i have `scrollview` which contain 4 `view` and i have four tabs which represent the section. Initially `view1 tab` active when i scroll `view2` become `visible` at that time `view2 tab` should be active.Let me know if anyone have the solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First should add `ScrollViewListener` to your scroll view

```
yourscrollview.setScrollViewListener(this)//replace yourscrollview with your scrollview and override onScrollChanged
```

then Create `variables` for all four `viewes`

Now here is the main part .In this we get height for  all four . And though scroll `position`  and `views heights` we check which view currently 
`visible` on the screen then you can `active` the tab.

Now in `onScrollChanged` method

```
override fun onScrollChanged(scrollView: ScrollViewExt?, x: Int, y: Int, oldx: Int, oldy: Int) {
    val scrollBounds = Rect()
    scrollView?.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds)
    var top4 = 0f
    var temp4:View = view4
    while (temp4 !is ScrollView){
        top4 += (temp4).y
        temp4 = temp4.parent as View
    }

    var top3 = 0f
    var temp3:View = view3
    while (temp3 !is ScrollView){
        top3 += (temp3).y
        temp3 = temp3.parent as View
    }
    var top2 = 0f
    var temp2:View = view2
    while (temp2 !is ScrollView){
        top2 += (temp2).y
        temp2 = temp2.parent as View
    }
    var top1 = 0f
    var temp1:View = view1
    while (temp1 !is ScrollView){
        top1 += (temp1).y
        temp1 = temp1.parent as View
    }

//this are the height of four views
    view1_height = top1 + view1.height
    view2_height = top2 + view2.height
    view3_height = top3 + view3.height
    view4_height = top4 + view4.height

//now check which view is visible . we go in descending order
    if (scrollBounds.bottom + view4.height >= view4_height {
            //4th view is visible
            //active your 4th tab    
        } else if (scrollBounds.bottom + view3.height >= view3_height {
          //3th view is visible
          //active your 3rd tab     
        } else if (scrollBounds.bottom + view2.height >= view2_height) {
          //2th view is visible
          //active your 2th tab 
        } else if ( scrollBounds.bottom + view1.height >= view1_height) {
              //1th view is visible
            //active your 1st tab   
        }
    }
```

I hope this will work for you.